# Last four rows of table view will not move out from under keyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a table view with four sections and a total of 21 rows, in which each cell contains a text field on the right side.

When I try to scroll and edit the cells at the bottom of the table view, I can't manage to get my last four to five cells properly positioned above the keyboard. The rest of the table is positioned fine.

I've called this method in `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` with `moveUp:YES` and in `textFieldShouldReturn:` with `NO`.

```
#define kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD 42
-(void)viewMoveUp:(BOOL)moveUp{

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5]; 

    CGRect rect = self.view.frame;
    if (moveUp)
    {
        rect.origin.y -= kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
        rect.size.height +=  kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
    }
    else
    {
        // revert back to the normal state.
        rect.origin.y = 0;
        rect.size.height =  360;
    }
    self.view.frame = rect;

    [UIView commitAnimations]; 


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it simpler.

Use a UITableViewController instead of a UIViewController.
The UITableViewController will handle the resizing on keyboard show for you.